# Commit with API - gitBucket

Tags: api, commit, gitbucket

I try to commit using API with GitBucket.
In the case of GitHub, we can commit using this API
"POST /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits".

But there are not any API about commit on GitBucket.
Accoding to this page...
https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/API-WebHook

Does anyone know how to commit using API with GitBucket?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, GitBucket doesn't support commit API. It supports only subset of GitHub's REST API.

Comment: Can you provide some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.31 (March 2019), Gitbucket supports to create and update file contents (one file per commit):

https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/API-WebHook

It is compatible with the GitHub API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents